# What algorithm does java use to typecast int to byte?

Tags: java, algorithm

How `byte b= (byte)400` is a valid statement although `400` is out of range? I want to know the algorithm java uses to bring `400` within byte's range.

Comment: You can find all details in the Oracle tutorial: [Conversions and Promotions#Narrowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (30 seconds google search though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes the least significant 8 bytes of the binary representation of 400 and assigns them to the `byte` variable.

The binary representation of the `int` 400 is :

```
00000000000000000000000110010000
                        --------
```

When taking the low 8 bits, you get `10010000`, which is the binary representation of -112.